# Entity Framework OnChanging protect primary keys

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a problem with implementing a check that stops a developer from manually or programmatically updating the primary key in code after the initial creation.

```
 partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.UserId = sGuid.NewSGuid(sGuidType.SequentialAtEnd);
    }

    partial void OnUserIdChanging(Guid value)
    {
        //throw if its an edit...
        throw new DbEntityValidationException("Cannot mutate primary key");
    }

}
```

This works fine if i'm editing/updating an object, but it won't actually let me create a new Entity in the first place.  Is there any way I can check at this point to see if its a new entity or an existing entity?

Thanks in advance,
Pete

UPDATE:

Typical I always find the answer after I post -_- !  Thanks for your answers guy, I'll mark one of yours as a correct answer as they were valid alternatives.

```
if (this.EntityState != System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
{
    throw new DbEntityValidationException("Cannot mutate primary key");
}
```

Comment: Well you could query the db with the key, if its there its an edit, if not, its a new object... or I am getting something wrong?

Comment: Why not just make your UserId setter private?

Comment: I did think of this (just setting it to private) which works. But it doesn't stop them from generating class methods that can update it.  But then I suppose it may not stop them from removing the check altogether.

At the onChanging event you just get the new value and if its been manually set you may get collision with the wrong record etc. 

The reason I want to avoid setting it private is because I've used the automatic code generation and it gets destroyed each time I update the model ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is usually solved by making primary key setters `private` or `protected`:

```
public class MyEntity
{
  public int Id { get; private set; }
}
```

If you're using EF designer, just select property in designer and set appropriate access modifier in the property grid - your code generator will do the rest.

Comment: Hi, see my comment above, I guess I wanted it at onChanging event to remove the possibility of anyone updating the classes internal methods and doing something stupid.  But if there's no way round it I guess I don't have a choice :(

Comment: @PeterLea You should focus more on warning the developer they're doing something wrong (if the fact that they're having to modify an internal method isn't clue enough, nothing is) than trying to eliminate stupidity altogether. I promise you, the latter is an impossible task. ;)